# Retry the WebClient based on the response

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I created a Spring webflux webclient.I want to repeat the same operation based on my response. For ex: if the data is still empty, I want to retry to get the data. How to do that ?

```
Flux<Data> data = webClient.get()
                .uri("/api/users?page=" + page)
                .retrieve()
                .flatMap(o -> {
                  o.subscribe(data -> {
                      if(data == null) {
                         // WHAT TO DO HERE, TO REPEAT THE SAME CALL ?
                         o.retry();
                      }
                });
                return o;
            })
            .bodyToFlux(Data.class);
```

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58021978/how-to-retry-spring-webclient-to-retry-the-operation-based-on-the-response

Comment: yea it's duplicate, but asked question in btr way. and was looking for an answer @Thomas

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `retry(Predicate<? super Throwable> retryMatcher)`, which will retry the operation based on the throwable condition.

In below code, I am returning Mono.error if the data received from the client is null, and then based on the error condition in the retry the above operation will be executed again.

You may also limit the number of retries with,

`retry(long numRetries, Predicate<? super Throwable> retryMatcher)`

```
final Flux<Data> flux = WebClient.create().get().uri("uri").exchange().flatMap(data -> {
      if (data == null)
        return Mono.error(new RuntimeException());
      return Mono.just(data);

    }).retry(throwable -> throwable instanceof RuntimeException)
        .flatMap(response -> response.bodyToMono(Data.class)).flux();
```